# The inverse of the digamma function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, special-functions, gamma-function, poly-gamma-function

The gamma function is increases on the interval $(x_0, \infty),$ where $x_0$ denotes the unique zero of the digamma function on the positive half line.

The inverse function of gamma function defined on
$(\Gamma(x_0),\infty)$ was shown to have an extension to a Pick-function in the cut plane $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,\Gamma(x_0)]$ (see [1]).

Do you have information for any similar result for digamma function or polygamma function?

[1] http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-04/S0002-9939-2011-11023-2/S0002-9939-2011-11023-2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

We want to solve for $x$ the equation
$$\psi ^{(0)}(x)=a$$

Just four months before your question, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.06547.pdf) gave tight bounds
$$x_{\text{min}}=\frac{1}{\log \left(1+e^{-x}\right)} \lt \psi^{-1} (x) \lt e^{x}+\frac{1}{2}=x_{\text{max}}$$

What I recently found very interesting is that is is much better to consider instead the equation
$$e^{\psi ^{(0)}(x)}=e^a$$ the lhs being very close to linearity.

Use the series expansion around $x=\alpha$
$$e^{\psi ^{(0)}(x)}=e^{\psi ^{(0)}(\alpha )}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{A_n}{n!}\,(x-\alpha)^n  \right)$$ where
$$A_1=\psi ^{(1)}(\alpha )$$
$$A_2=\psi ^{(1)}(\alpha )^2+\psi ^{(2)}(\alpha )$$
$$A_3=\psi ^{(1)}(\alpha )^3+3 \psi ^{(2)}(\alpha ) \psi ^{(1)}(\alpha
   )+\psi ^{(3)}(\alpha )$$ and so forth.

Truncate to some order $p$ and use [power series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) to get
$$x=\alpha +t+\sum_{n=2}^p B_n\, t^n \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac{e^{a-\psi ^{(0)}(\alpha )}-1}{\psi ^{(1)}(\alpha )}$$ the very first coefficients being
$$B_2=\frac{-\psi ^{(1)}(\alpha )^2-\psi ^{(2)}(\alpha )}{2 \psi
   ^{(1)}(\alpha )}$$
$$B_3=\frac{2 \psi ^{(1)}(\alpha )^4+3 \psi ^{(2)}(\alpha ) \psi
   ^{(1)}(\alpha )^2-\psi ^{(3)}(\alpha ) \psi ^{(1)}(\alpha )+3
   \psi ^{(2)}(\alpha )^2}{6 \psi ^{(1)}(\alpha )^2}$$
and so forth.

Trying for $a=\pi$ for different orders of expansion starting at the midpoint

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & x_{(p)} \\
 1 & 23.6388933011739 \\
 2 & 23.6388924116017 \\
 3 & 23.6388924311562 \\
 4 & 23.6388924307264 \\
 5 & 23.6388924307358 \\
 6 & 23.6388924307356 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$